# IE9 Issue: Text in div is aligned to bottom

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have anchors that are separated by `&nbsp;|&nbsp;`. This is all wrapped in a `div.linksWrapper`. In IE9 any text (in this case `&nbsp;|&nbsp;`) that is a direct descendant of `div.linksWrapper` is offset from the center of the other elements. In all other browsers `&nbsp;|&nbsp;` renders aligned with the anchors.

See image below...

[image]

html

```
<div class="instagramViewerWrapper">
    <div class="linksWrapper">
        <a class="active" href="#">VIEW ALL</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a id="40020931" href="#" class="">KATHERINE</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a id="40027696" href="#" class="">MELISSA</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a id="42768724" href="#">MICHELE</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a id="42764826" href="#">CAILEE</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a id="42767242" href="#">CHRISTIE</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a id="42763829" href="#">JAMIE</a></div>
    <div class="grid" id="instagramViewer">...</div>
</div>
```

css

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, code, em, img, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.instagramViewerWrapper {
    color: #888888;
    margin-top: 30px;
    min-height: 1040px;
}
.instagramViewerWrapper .linksWrapper {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.instagramViewerWrapper .linksWrapper a {
    color: #888888;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply caused by the fact that you're applying `padding-bottom: 5px;` on your anchors (`.instagramViewerWrapper .linksWrapper a`). Apparently other browsers ignore it, but not IE.

Either move the rule declaration to include all of `.instagramViewerWrapper .linksWrapper`, or remove it altogether.

Hope that helped!

Comment: This explains **why** the vertical pipes are misaligned, but leaves the OP with some really dirty code ;-)

Comment: @ZoltanToth Well, I believe the question is "why are the pipes misaligned?" vs. "what's the best way to make vertical separators between some inline elements?" On the other hand, I do agree that this method isn't the best at all. Probably not even close to be good. Again, I was just trying to answer the question :) `borders` are definitely the way to do this.

Comment: I'll try this with borders instead. I like that idea. Thank you Abody97

Comment: i disagree, borders are not as flexible in styling as semantics, so i think the best solution is to use the pseudo selector `:after`. This way you don't have the ugly semantics while you are still be able to style the separator.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using some non-semantic separators like `&nbsp;|&nbsp;`, you can do this:

```
.instagramViewerWrapper .linksWrapper a {
    color: #888888;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px 5px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

This will draw a border to your links, so they will be aligned with the text and your code will be much cleaner too.

Comment: This doesn't explain **why** the vertical pipes are misaligned, though.

Comment: No it doesn't Abody, it tells the OP how to avoid using them altogether.